# Get position of a sprite in cocos2d-x

Tags: get, position, cocos2d-x, sprite

I want get the position of a sprite but I don't know how... I tried to use mySprite->getLocation() but it says me that there is no member called that.
Help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should call 
    mySprite->getPosition().

Comment: if I call mySprite->getPosition().x it don't work... how can I receive the X position of the sprite?

Comment: mySprite->getPositionX()